# c# - Generate xml with table constraints as tags and column names as value

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I need to generate an XML like the below one with constraints as tags and column name as values for a specific DB table in c#.

```
<tablename>
<key>ProductId</key>
<composite>
<column>ProductId</column>
<column>ProductCode</column>
<composite>
<ForeignKey>
<column>ProductBaseId</column>
</ForeignKey>
</tablename>
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Please can you share some code you have tried? And what do u prefer to write XML?

Comment: in which format your data has? I mean, where is your tablename, key, column, foreign key etc? In database? or you have built a list class to hold them?

Comment: No... I need to get all those details from Database

Comment: Ok, Then you have to query from SQL to get the table schema. You will not find all info from a single system table. You have to join several to query out key, composite key, foreign keys. Then store them in a list or datatable, and then write to XML. Do you get the workflow?

Comment: Ok... Can you please share some links to get a better idea on this?

Comment: Ok, I am updating an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here you will find the primary key:**

```
SELECT Col.Column_Name from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    AND Col.Table_Name = 'tablename'
```

If you have multiple PRIMARY KEYS, then you will get them from the same query above. You can just count the primary key and if they are more than 1 then you can list them in Composite. Otherwise just put them as Key.

Here is another point, If there are two primary keys, then what will be in **<KEY> tag**?

**Here you will find Foreign Keys:**

```
SELECT Col.Column_Name from 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND Constraint_Type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
    AND Col.Table_Name = 'tablename'
```

Just join two information and write in XML. XML writing is so easy, here you can find it. [XML Writing - DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter)

**UPDATE 1 :**
Here is a code, where you can find the `pK` and `FK` both and with type from single query.

```
    SELECT Col.Column_Name, 
Case When( CHARINDEX('PK_' , Col.CONSTRAINT_NAME) >0 ) Then 'PK' ELSE 'FK' END as Type
 from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND (Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'  OR Constraint_Type = 'Foreign KEY')

    AND Col.Table_Name = 'table_1'
```

**The Query output will like below:**

```
Column_Name    Type

AnotherID        FK
Code             PK
ID               PK
```

**I know it's not good that, I am providing codes fully. but as it was interesting to me, I have wrote some lines that may helpful to others also.**

Here is the full code :

```
    namespace XMLWritingFromDB
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static string connectionstring = "Data Source=RAHIMPC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=false;uid=******;pwd=********";
        public static SqlConnection conn;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Get the table Informations 
            DataTable dt = GetDataSchema("table_1"); // PUT YOUR TABLE NAME HERE.
            string xmlDocument = PrepareXml(dt);
            Console.Write(xmlDocument);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        public static DataTable GetDataSchema(string TableName)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string query = "SELECT Col.Column_Name, Case When( CHARINDEX('PK_' , Col.CONSTRAINT_NAME) >0 ) Then 'PK' ELSE 'FK' END as Type " +
                " from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col " +
                " WHERE Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name " +
                "AND (Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'  OR Constraint_Type = 'Foreign KEY') AND Col.Table_Name = '"+TableName+"'";

            using (conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = sc.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        dt.Load(dr);
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            return dt;
        }

        public static string PrepareXml(DataTable dt)
        {
            int pkCount = 0, fkCount = 0;
            List<string> lstPK = new List<string>();
            List<string> lstFK = new List<string>();
            //Build data for xml
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (dr[1].ToString().Contains("PK"))
                {
                    pkCount++;
                    lstPK.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                }
                if (dr[1].ToString().Contains("FK"))
                {
                    fkCount++;
                    lstFK.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                }
            }

            List<TableName> lstXml = new List<TableName>();
            TableName xml = new TableName();
            xml.key = lstPK[lstPK.Count() - 1].ToString();

            xml.ForeignKey = lstFK;
            if (pkCount > 1)
                xml.Composite = lstPK;

            var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(xml.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, xml);
            return stringwriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("TableName")]
    public class TableName
    {
        public string key { get; set; }

        [XmlArray(ElementName = "Composite")]
        [XmlArrayItem("ColumnName", Type = typeof(string))]
        public List<string> Composite { get; set; }

        [XmlArray(ElementName = "ForeignKey")]
        [XmlArrayItem("ColumnName", Type = typeof(string))]
        public List<string> ForeignKey { get; set; } 

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... :) This was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataTableObject.WriteXml()` method, this method contains various overloads.